# Visual Studio 2022 .net Core 7 - Build project without Debug or Release folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I am working on a .net Core 7 Class Library project. For debuging purposes the project should build to a specific folder and for this I need to build the project without the Debug or Release folder which is automatically added to the build path.

So normaly you build to: bin\Debug and I want to build lets say to ..\Gui\bin\Debug\Plugin

What have I tried already:

- Change the Base Output Path in the project settings.
  The base path is indeed changed with this setting but the Debug (or Release) folder is still appended automatically.
- Append AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath in the Project File under PropertyGroup. -> This removes the net7.0 subfolder (in the debug folder)
- Append AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath in the Project File under PropertyGroup. -> This removes the runtime identifier (in the debug folder)

I need the project to build exactly in one specific folder because I want to consume the build dll with MEF in another program. (Of course I can build and move the dll, but I am indeed a lazy programmer :))

The only thing i can think about (as a workaround) is a post build event which copies the build dll to my desired folder, but is there realy no way to tell visual studio to not automaticaly add a folder on build?

Comment: *but is there realy no way to tell visual studio to not automaticaly add a folder on build?* Yes, by using a pre- och post build action. Besides, the .NET SDK expects the binaries to be located in specific folders depending on which command(s) you execute and in what order, for example `dotnet build ...` followed by `dotnet test ... --no-build`.  If you build from the command-line, you can easily specify an output folder.

Comment: If you are indeed lazy, then add a post build action to copy the artifact to wherever you like, or create a symlink.

Comment: Symlink, yes that is also a good idea (for testing purpose) thank you :)

Comment: I prefer to use the donet command line. This is more applicable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to tell Visual Studio to do something in relation to a build would be to the pre- and/or post-build actions.

Besides, the .NET SDK expects the binaries to be located in specific folders depending on which command(s) you execute and in what order, for example a `dotnet build ...` followed by `dotnet test ... --no-build`.

If you build from the command-line using the SDK, you can easily specify an output folder.